# How to make tab and window active when result is found?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

I want to bring the tab the extension is running on to the front of my window as soon as the match is found, even if I am currently working in a second window.

So far I have this code in my **content_script.js**, but it doesn't seem to work.
The  commented lines were my last failed tries.

The alert gave me **-1**, which seems to be quite the weird tab id.

```
if(output == 'found') {
    sendResponse({findresult: "yes"});

    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        //chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {selected: true});
        //chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {active: true});
        alert(sender.tab.id);
    });
}
```

I've tried some things in the **background.html** too and all kinds of things already posted here, all with no luck.

What do I need to do to make this work?

**EDIT**

**manifest.json** script inclusion

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [ {
    "all_frames": false,
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "content_script.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
    "run_at": "document_idle"
}
```

**background.js** (the alert won't even show up)

```
alert("here");

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    your_tab_Id = sender.tab.id);
});

chrome.tabs.update(your_tab_Id,{"active":true,"highlighted":true},function (tab){
    console.log("Completed updating tab .." + JSON.stringify(tab));
});
```

**content_script.js** jQuery change background (sendResponse works, but if I activate the background changing line the script stops working)

```
if(found === true) {
            //$('td:contains('+foundItem+')').css("background", "greenyellow");
            sendResponse({findresult: "yes"});
        }
```

[jsFiddle I tested the jQuery code in](http://jsfiddle.net/bZKpq/2/)

EDIT 2
[extension download](http://www.mediafire.com/?vmlnwzx8aqqge8g)

Comment: Do you want to highlight a tab when your logic meets true for a particular tab?

Comment: @Sudarshan If highlighting means bringing it to the front they yes. I want the tab I'm using the extension in and its window to be brought to the front when the match is found.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) API() from content script

#### References

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)

To get tab id put your code to `background.js`

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        your_tab_Id = sender.tab.id);
});
```

and add this to `background.js` page

```
chrome.tabs.update(your_tab_Id,{"active":true,"highlighted":true},function (tab){
  console.log("Completed updating tab .." + JSON.stringify(tab));
});
```

Use only content script to send messages

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage("Awesome message");
```

---

**Edit 1:**

Your code do not work because of syntax error

Some point to consider:

- *Use [onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage) instead of onRequest ( onRequest is deprecated in favour of onMessage)*
- *All the used API's are [asynchronous](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#sync) so make sure they are called synchronously.*
- *Use [`sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage) in content script as well ( sendRequest is deprecated in favour of sendMessage)*

After applying above changes your code turns as shown here.

```
alert("here");

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    your_tab_Id = sender.tab.id;
    chrome.tabs.update(your_tab_Id,{"active":true,"highlighted":true},function (tab){
        console.log("Completed updating tab .." + JSON.stringify(tab));
    });
});
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to get this to work at all. I've added a `background.js` to the manifest `{
  "background": {
  "page": ["background.html"],
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
 "browser_action": {...` and added your code to the new javascript file, but nothing happens.

Comment: I also have another question if you don't mind. I've added jQuery to the manifest to use in the `content_script.js` 
 `"content_scripts": [ {
  "all_frames": false,
  "js": [ "jquery.js", "content_script.js" ],` but if I try to use it, e.g. `$('td:contains('+foundItem +')').css("background", "greenyellow");` the script stops and I'm pretty sure it's because it can't handle the selector. Again, what am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: It worked for me put your `background.js` by editing your question, by the way you do not need `"page": ["background.html"]` in your manifest. for `$('td:contains('+foundItem +')').css("background", "greenyellow");` what does your foundItem contain, put your html code expected for this script by editing your question, will pick it  up from there

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me :) I've taken out the `"page": ["background.html"]` from my manifest. The variable `foundItem` contains a word from an array that was matched with the document's text. The match works fine and the variable is filled correctly, so that can't be the problem. I've updated the question with the relevant code snippets.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the fast answer! But sadly it still isn't working, not even the alert. I've edited the question with a link to download the whole extension (including a !readme) I'm working on, if you could maybe take a look at that? I'll delete the link and update the question with the relevant code as soon as I find out what's going wrong. Because right now I really have not a single clue what I'm missing.

Comment: @spiel: have added `"manifest_version":2` to manifest.json file i got alert working.

Comment: I've specified `"manifest_version": 2,` at the top of the manifest, but the alert still isn't working. Do you per chance have any other guesses?